# How to prevent table row with colspan from messing up the automatic size of other columns when its content is too long

Tags: html, css, html-table, row

I have a relatively straightforward html table, with rows that can be clicked to toggle the display of the row below them (used to display more details for the row above).

The "detail" row that is displayed/hidden on click has a `colspan` value set so that a single `td` spans all the columns.

The table takes 100% of the available horizontal space at all time.

I'm facing an issue that I do not understand: when the "detail" row content overflows on multiple lines, it triggers a change in the width of all the columns!

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>asdf</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>AAA</th>
            <th>BBB</th>
            <th>CCC</th>
            <th>DDD</th>
            <th>EEE</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr onclick="document.getElementById('detail').hidden = !document.getElementById('detail').hidden" style="background-color:red">
            <td>asdfa</td>
            <td>dhfdh dfhd hfdfdh  fdh dhdhd</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="detail">
            <td colspan="5">
                ssssssss ssssssssssss ssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssssss ssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssss ssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssss sssssssss ssssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssss ssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssss sssssssssssss sssssssssssss ssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssss ssssssss ssssssssssss ssssssssss ssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssss sssssssssssssss ssssssssssss
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>asdfasdf</td>
            <td>dgfhdh sdgdfdh</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/93dpowb5/ (click the red row to toggle the display of the "detail" row)

I managed to reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle. (tested on Firefox and Chrome)

I noticed that setting a `max-width` on the "detail" row fixes the issue (columns widths stay the same), but I would like to avoid doing that so the window can be resized normally.

I know about `table-layout: fixed` but I want my columns to be dynamically sized. I just want them to stay the same width once the layout is computed!

Basically I'm looking for an as-much-as-possible-non-hacky way to leave everything dynamically sized, while avoiding the jumpy columns when the "detail" row shows...

Comment: I tested your fiddle in three browsers on my Mac. I can observe the behaviour you describe in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari does the job perfectly, no jumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide `div` in `tr`:

```css
body {
  overflow: scroll; /* just prevent jump */
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

.hidden td {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.hidden div {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>AAA</th>
      <th>BBB</th>
      <th>CCC</th>
      <th>DDD</th>
      <th>EEE</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr onclick="detail.classList.toggle('hidden')" style="background-color:red">
      <td>asdfa</td>
      <td>dhfdh dfhd hfdfdh  fdh dhdhd</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="detail">
      <td colspan="5">
        <div>ssssssss ssssssssssss ssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssssss ssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssss ssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssss sssssssss ssssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssss ssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssss ssssssssssss sssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss ssssssss sssssssssssss sssssssssssss ssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssss ssssssss ssssssssssss ssssssssss ssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssss sssssssssss sssssssssssssss ssssssssssss</div>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>asdfasdf</td>
      <td>dgfhdh sdgdfdh</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ooh so the trick is actually not using `display: none`, and hiding the row by setting its height to 0 instead!

Thank you!

It feels a little bit like a hack but it works. The only thing now is manage to make the row actually have a height of 0. I'm not sure why but it seems it always wants to be at least 1px high... Still better than before I think...

EDIT: ah no actually it's not that hard with `.hidden { visibility: collapse; }`!

Comment: Ah actually it only works if the content of the collapsible row never changes, and in my actual project my example is base on, the content is dynamically generated when the row is expanded, so it doesn't work there TT...
I'm more and more convinced it is not possible to keep the initial dynamic sizing of the columns then keep it as-is when the `td` content changes afterward (even though with a colspan encompassing all cells it shouldn't change anything. Maybe this can be considered a browser bug...)